# Chart js scatter - display label on hover

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I've cobbled together a chart js scatter graph - which works pretty much ok.

In the bottom part of this js, I have a function that gets the label of the point clicked so that I can do stuff with it - this is working fine.

What I can't do is get this label to display when the user hovers over the point - I just get the x and y values of the data point.

[image]

I want the relevant label to appear when the user hovers over. Ideally, I'd like the x and y values not to.

How do I do that?

Thanks,

```
<script>var data = {
        datasets: [{
                  backgroundColor: "#566573",
                  {{scatterData|safe}}
                  }],
                  {{labelsData|safe}}
                };

                $(document).ready(
                  function () {
                    var canvas = document.getElementById("myChart");
                    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                    var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                      type: 'bubble',
                      data: data,
                options : {
                    legend: {
                        display: false
                     },
                        scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                          scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Page Value'
                          }
                        }],
                        xAxes: [{
                          scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Unique Page Views'
                          }
                        }]                      }
                    }
                    });
                    canvas.onclick = function (evt) {
                      var activePoints = myNewChart.getElementsAtEvent(evt);
                      var chartData = activePoints[0]['_chart'].config.data;
                      var idx = activePoints[0]['_index'];
                      var label = chartData.labels[idx];
                      var value = chartData.datasets[0].data[idx];
                      loadScatterPoint(label);
                    };
                  }
                );
    </script>
```

Comment: but, you are creating  a bubble chart not scatter

Comment: ...a very good point indeed. So question is, can I put labels onto this bubble chart?

Comment: you want something like... `Ben: (3719, 0, 3)` on tooltip?

Comment: Exactly - you got it

Comment: So that injects `data: [{x:3719, y:0, r:3},{x:2652, y:0, r:3}],` into the page

Comment: and `{{labelsData|safe}}` injects `labels: ["point 1","point 2","point 3"],`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `click` event handler for your chart.

To display a label on tooltip, you would have to define the `label` property for you dataset, like so ...

```
var data = {
   datasets: [{
      label: 'Ben Mayo',  //<-- define this
      backgroundColor: "#566573",
      { { scatterData | safe } }
   }],
   { { labelsData | safe } }
};
```

***note:*** `labels` array are not applicable for bubble chart.

Comment: But doesn't that put the same label over every point? I'm trying to get a different label over each different point.

Comment: Yes, that's how bubble chart works. If you want diff. labels then you need to create multiple datasets like above and define diff. label for each one.

Answer (score -1):

I think you better to use angular-chart js. they have few examples there
http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/